# R: [read_delim()] - Getting a warning, how to get rid of it?

Tags: r, warnings

I'm new to R. I have a code that reads from a file without headers and selects the very first two elements from each line. Each line determines an airplane route. The first element describes the airport name from where it takesoff and the second element the airport name where it lands.

Structure from one out of the thousands of lines from the file:

```
LFPO;LFSL;00;AT45;210;LFPO;LFSL;189930747;150907;1815;!!!!;HOP25ZZ;HOP;0;HOP25ZZ-LFPO-LFSL-20150907180500;N;0;;;245346;;;150907;1805;0;;X;;;;;;;;;;210;;0;20150907175900;AA45458325;;;;;NEXE;NEXE;;;;;20150907180500;;;;245346;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;HOP;;;;;;;;;;;0
```

What my code does is from out of all the airports, rank the top ten based on the total number of movements that an airport has, that's calculated  from the total number of landings and takeoffs that an airport has during the period of time specified in the file.

The code works and I'm tryng to improve it using better libraries or functions. So far I swap the read.table() function for read_delim() which has improved the processing time quite drastically. Nevertheless, I get some warnings althought printing the desired results.

How do I get rid of the warnings or how can I sort out the warnings?

This is the code and here a link to a test file https://easyupload.io/4lw4o4:

```
start_time <- Sys.time()
# Libraries
library(compare)
library(janitor)
library(data.table)
library(readr)[enter image description here][1]


# START
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
# test if there is at least one argument
if (length(args)==0) {
  fileName  = "traffic1week.exp2"
} else if (length(args)==1) {
  # default output file
  fileName = args[1]
}

# Convert file to dataframe
df = read_delim(fileName, delim = ";", col_names =F)

# Read file
names(df) = c("Airport","Airport")

# Retrieve 1st column
origin = df[1]# takeOff Airports
# Retrieve 2nd column
destination = df[2] # Landing Airports

# Number of movements
takeOff_airports = unlist(table(origin)) 
landing_airports = unlist(table(destination))

# Convert to dataframes
df1 = as.data.frame(takeOff_airports)
names(df1) = c('Airport', 'TakeOffs')
df2 = as.data.frame(landing_airports)
names(df2) = c('Airport', 'Landings')

# Merge both dataframes
df3 = merge(df1, df2, all=T)

# Sum colum[3] values from each dataframe
df3$Total_Movements = df3$TakeOffs+df3$Landings

# Orde by max total movements
df3 = df3[order(-df3$Total_Movements),]

# Reorganize columns
result = df3[, c(1, 4, 2, 3)]

# Print results 
print(result[1:10,], row.names = FALSE)

# STOP
end_time = Sys.time()
cat(paste("Processing time: ", end_time - start_time),sep="\n\n")
```

This are the warnings:

```
Attaching package: ‘compare’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

isTRUE


Attaching package: ‘janitor’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

chisq.test, fisher.test

Parsed with column specification:
cols(
.default = col_logical(),
X1 = col_character(),
X2 = col_character(),
X3 = col_character(),
X4 = col_character(),
X5 = col_character(),
X6 = col_character(),
X7 = col_character(),
X8 = col_double(),
X9 = col_double(),
X10 = col_character(),
X11 = col_character(),
X12 = col_character(),
X13 = col_character(),
X14 = col_double(),
X15 = col_character(),
X16 = col_character(),
X17 = col_double(),
X20 = col_double(),
X23 = col_double(),
X24 = col_character()
# ... with 13 more columns
)
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
Warning message:
The `names` must have length 95, not 2.
This warning is displayed once per session. 
Airport Total_Movements TakeOffs Landings
LFPG            9407     4926     4481
EHAM            9399     4879     4520
LTBA            9384     4749     4635
EGLL            9057     4749     4308
EDDF            8930     4624     4306
EDDM            7535     3816     3719
LEMD            7412     3789     3623
LIRF            6957     3528     3429
LEBL            6406     3221     3185
EGKK            5995     3050     2945
Processing time:  1.78606390953064
```

I'd like to get just:

```
Airport Total_Movements TakeOffs Landings
LFPG            9407     4926     4481
EHAM            9399     4879     4520
LTBA            9384     4749     4635
EGLL            9057     4749     4308
EDDF            8930     4624     4306
EDDM            7535     3816     3719
LEMD            7412     3789     3623
LIRF            6957     3528     3429
LEBL            6406     3221     3185
EGKK            5995     3050     2945
Processing time:  1.78606390953064
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the warnings are.

Comment: Your are totally right, I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning give by packages when loaded are normal. They are just informative. There's a way to suppress messages, by using the `suppressMessages()`, but if you suppress every message at all in your program, you might risk missing some important message in the case of an exception.

Try this

```
suppressMessages(library(compare))
```

As for the warnings given by `read_delim()`, they are just informing you of the class types asssumed for each column, since you didn't specify them yourself. If you pass the `colClasses` parameter to `read_delim()`, it will stop babbling. You may also suppress these messages by placing `read_delim()` inside `suppressMessage()` or `suppressWarnings()`, as mentioned above. Or if you use `read.table()` instead, it quietly assumes reasonable types for the columns without emitting messages about it.

Comment: It did work, not shure it it's very elegant thou....I was using read.table but it was taking almost 10 times more to prrocess the same code.